# getting unknown error in xml file in drawables

Tags: android, xml

I found this error on my android studio when I upload project

See Below Image Error:

[image]

```
C:\Users\faizy\AndroidStudioProjects\Child-Monitoring-System- 
master\Child-Monitoring-System- 
master\app\src\main\res\Drawable\button_rounded.xml: Error: Unsupported 
type 'solid'
```

Comment: Please share code of `drawable` file

Comment: post you code for **button_rounded.xml** .. you have done something wrong to your **<solid android:color="color_here"/>**

Comment: i cannot find "button_rounded.xml" in android studio

Comment: this is the coding of that xml file

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="20dp">
        <solid android:color="@color/orange" />
        <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
    </shape>